# How to reference dynamic textboxes created at run time?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, reference, textbox

I have an ASP project which references a WCF service. Does exactly half of what I need.

A button on the page calls a function from the WCF, which returns a list of objects (variable names). When returned, the vb code dynamically adds textboxes to a panel on the page. Like this:

```
    For Each LetterVariables In LetterVarList
        tb = New TextBox
        lb = New Label
        lb.Text = LetterVariables._key & "  "
        tb.ID = LetterVariables._key
        pnlVars.Controls.Add(lb)
        pnlVars.Controls.Add(tb)
        Dim LineBreak As LiteralControl = New LiteralControl("<br />")
        pnlVars.Controls.Add(LineBreak)
    Next
```

Now the problem is, after this is finished the user will enter some values into those texboxes. I (somehow) need to reference those texboxes to snag the values when a user clicks another button.

How can I do this?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the TextBox an ID which you could use FindControl to retrieve.

```
tb.ID = "txt" + LetterVariables._key.ToString();
```

Then when you want to reference it.

```
TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)FindControl("txt" + someKey);
```

Something like that might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to recreate the controls on post back BEFORE the controls are loaded with the posted values.

Comment: Override LoadViewState and put code like what you got above in it.  I'm not sure how you get your LetterVarList, but you can keep stuff in the ViewState if you can't recreate LetterVarList easily.